# Use metaclass to allow forward declarations

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I want to do something decidedly unpythonic. I want to create a class that allows for forward declarations of its class attributes. (If you must know, I am trying to make some sweet syntax for parser combinators.)

This is the kind of thing I am trying to make:

```
a = 1
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
    b = a  # Refers to something outside the class
    c = d + b  # Here's a forward declaration to 'd'
    d = 1  # Declaration resolved
```

My current direction is to make a metaclass so that when `d` is not found I catch the `NameError` exception and return an instance of some dummy class I'll call `ForwardDeclaration`. I take some inspiration from [`AutoEnum`](https://bugs.python.org/issue26988), which uses metaclass magic to declare enum values with bare identifiers and no assignment.

Below is what I have so far. The missing piece is: how do I continue normal name resolution and catch the `NameError`s:

```
class MetaDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self._forward_declarations = dict()
    def __getitem__(self,  key):
        try:
            ### WHAT DO I PUT HERE ??? ###
            # How do I continue name resolution to see if the
            # name already exists is the scope of the class
        except NameError:
            if key in self._forward_declarations:
                return self._forward_declarations[key]
            else:
                new_forward_declaration = ForwardDeclaration()
                self._forward_declarations[key] = new_forward_declaration
                return new_forward_declaration

class MyMeta(type):
    def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases):
        return MetaDict()

class MyBaseClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass

class ForwardDeclaration:
    # Minimal behavior
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return ForwardDeclaration(self.value + other)
```

Comment: Couldn't you resolve this by using default arguments(attributes in this case) ?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, that won't work because I won't know at the time I define `MyBaseClass` what the attributes of `MyClass` will be. If I did, you would be correct; I could just declare them all like `d = ForwardDeclaration()` in the base class.

Comment: This sounds hilariously disgusting! Well done! It's not clear though what the specific issue / question is?

Answer (score 1):

To start with:

```
    def __getitem__(self,  key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
             ...
```

But that won't allow you to retrieve the global variables outside the class body. 
You can also use the `__missin__` method which is reserved exactly for subclasses of  dict:

```
class MetaDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self._forward_declarations = dict()

    # Just leave __getitem__ as it is on "dict"
    def __missing__(self,  key):
        if key in self._forward_declarations:
            return self._forward_declarations[key]
        else:
            new_forward_declaration = ForwardDeclaration()
            self._forward_declarations[key] = new_forward_declaration
            return new_forward_declaration
```

As you can see, that is not that "UnPythonic" - advanced Python stuff such as SymPy and SQLAlchemy have to resort to this kind of behavior to do their nice magic - just be sure to get it very well documented and tested.

Now, to allow for global (module) variables, you have a to get a little out of the way - and possibly somthing that may not be avaliablein all Python implementations - that is: introspecting the frame where the class body is to get its globals:

```
import sys
...
class MetaDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self._forward_declarations = dict()

    # Just leave __getitem__ as it is on "dict"
    def __missing__(self,  key):
        class_body_globals = sys._getframe().f_back.f_globals
        if key in class_body_globals:
             return class_body_globals[key]
        if key in self._forward_declarations:
            return self._forward_declarations[key]
        else:
            new_forward_declaration = ForwardDeclaration()
            self._forward_declarations[key] = new_forward_declaration
            return new_forward_declaration
```

Now that you are here - your special dictionaries are good enough to avoid NameErrors, but your `ForwardDeclaration` objects are far from smart enough -  when running:

```
a = 1
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
    b = a  # Refers to something outside the class
    c = d + b  # Here's a forward declaration to 'd'
    d = 1
```

What happens is that `c` becomes a `ForwardDeclaration` object, but summed to the instant value of `d` which is zero. On the next line, `d` is simply overwritten with the value `1` and is no longer a lazy object. So you might just as well declare `c = 0 + b` .

To overcome this, `ForwardDeclaration`  has to be a class designed in a smartway, so that its values are always lazily evaluated, and it behaves as in the "reactive programing" approach: i.e.: updates to a value will  cascade updates into all other values that depend on it. I think giving you a full implementation of a working  "reactive" aware FOrwardDeclaration class falls off the scope of this question. - I have some toy code to do that on github at https://github.com/jsbueno/python-react , though.

Even with a proper "Reactive"  ForwardDeclaration class, you have to fix your dictionary again so that the `d = 1` class works:

```
class MetaDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self._forward_declarations = dict()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self._forward_declarations:
            self._forward_declations[key] = value
            # Trigger your reactive update here if your approach is not
            # automatic
            return None
         return super().__setitem__(key, value)
    def __missing__(self,  key):
        # as above
```

And finally, there is a way to avoid havign to implement a fully reactive aware class - you can resolve all pending FOrwardDependencies on the `__new__` method of the metaclass - (so that your ForwardDeclaration objects are manually "frozen" at class creation time, and no further worries - )

Something along:

```
from functools import reduce

sentinel = object()
class ForwardDeclaration:
    # Minimal behavior
    def __init__(self, value=sentinel, dependencies=None):
        self.dependencies = dependencies or []
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ForwardDeclaration):
             return ForwardDeclaration(dependencies=self.dependencies + [self])
        return ForwardDeclaration(self.value + other)

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
         for key, value in list(attrs.items()):
              if not isinstance(value, ForwardDeclaration): continue
              if any(v.value is sentinel for v in value.dependencies): continue
              attrs[key] = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b.value, value.dependencies, 0) 

         return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)
    def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases):
        return MetaDict()
```

And, depending on your class hierarchy and what exactly you are doing, rememebr to also update one class' dict `_forward_dependencies` with the `_forward_dependencies` created on its ancestors.
AND if you need any operator other than `+`, as you will have noted, you will have to keep information on the operator itself  - at this point, hou might as well jsut use  `sympy`.

Comment: The search for existing names needs to include `__builtins__` which is searched after `f_globals`.

Comment: The search for existing names needs also to examine the variables of outer scopes (if `MyClass` is defined in a function, which itself may be defined in a function). I looked in `inspect` but could not figure out how to walk the outer scope of a frame.

Comment: Rather than messing with `f_globals` and `__builtins__`, you can just raise a `KeyError` and that'll happen automatically. Doesn't let you check for presence though. I didn't find anything in the docs mentioning it, but it's in [cpython's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d1a0a960ee493262fb95a0f5b795b5b6d75cecb8/Python/ceval.c#L2795-L2803).

Comment: @Kyuuhachi I don't think that will work here. I want to be able to run code (creation of forward declaration) if the name is not defined in the local, nonlocal, global, or builtin scopes. If I raise a `KeyError`, I give up control and cannot recover if the name is not defined. If you know how to catch the subsequent `NameError` here, I would love to hear it.